# jQuery date validation alert message (yyyy-mm-dd) not working

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#From_Date label.control input', function (event) {
    var txtfdate=document.querySelector('#From_Date label.control input ').value;

    if(txtfdate.match(/^(19|20)\d\d-(0\d|1[012])-(0\d|1\d|2\d|3[01])$/i)==null){
        alert("Enter From_Date in YYYY-MM-DD format only");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Correct..."+txtfdate);
    }
});
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: code never speaks!! you have to tell us whats problem with this code.

Comment: i am not getting any alert message..

Comment: shouldn't you use `.test()` instead?

Comment: You're not getting **either** alert? Did you check your console for errors? Did you add a `console.log()` to see if the handler is fired?

Comment: Do you think this is correct `document.querySelector('#From_Date label.control input ').value;` i think this should be `jQuery('#From_Date label.control input')[0].value;`

Comment: Do you have any element that would match the selector? Would you like to show the HTML code for it? Why are you using `querySelector` when you are using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

use this regular expression

```
txtfdate.match(/^\d{4}-((0\d)|(1[012]))-(([012]\d)|3[01])$/);
```

check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BWP6H/3/)